# The download speed is very small on 3G+ network

Tags: android, download, inputstream, httpurlconnection

Hi,

When I use my application with a wifi network, I could download some images really fast

The code looks like this:

```
URL url = new URL(mAdresse);
mHttpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

mHttpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
mHttpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

mInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(mHttpURLConnection.getInputStream());
```

...but when I try it on a 3G+ network, it takes a very long time to download the pictures.
The application gets stuck on the following command for a long time:

```
mHttpURLConnection.getInputStream()
```

I was searching for the reason of why this takes so long, for several days (and nights) without success.

My question is: **Why does it take so long?**

Answer (score 2):

different networks will download at different speeds. how much impact this has on your application depends very much on your application and how much content you are downloading. if you add some logging to your application, so that you know exactly how much content you are downloading, you should be able to determine how much impact the network would have on your application. if you know the expected relative speeds of the two networks, using advertised numbers or speed tests, you could even predict for your application, how fast the slower network would take, based on the measurements you'd taken and logged. if you find, then, that your application is performing more slowly than expected, then you have a problem.